# Получения результата выполнения Shell команды

Tags: c++, c

На самом деле долгое время пытался заставить нормально работать это на основе `_popen` - такая реализация не подходит поскольку работает непонятным образом. Она то работает, то в возвращаемом значении какой-то мусор, то не работает вообще.

Прошу помочь! Я пытался реализовать что-то подобное с помощью `CreatePipe()`, но у меня ничего не вышло. Поможет любая информация. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Для получения кода возврата команды, запущенной `popen()` надо исследовать результат `rc =`[pclose()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pclose).

`rc == -1` -- ошибка

Иначе, если `WIFEXITED(rc)`, то `cmd_code = WEXITSTATUS(rc)`,
иначе, если `WIFSIGNALED(rc)`, то `sig_no = WTERMSIG(rc)`

Подробнее см. [man waitpid](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid)

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите [tiny-process-library](https://gitlab.com/eidheim/tiny-process-library):

```
std::string output;

TinyProcessLib::Process proc("echo Hello World", "", [](const char *data, std::size_t size) {
    output.insert(output.end(), data, data + size);
});

if (proc.get_exit_status()) // Дожидается завершения процесса, возвращает код результата.
{ /* Ошибка */ }

std::cout << output << '\n';
```

Код писал на глазок, но должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам действительно нужен *именно* код возврата:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int ret;
    // измените /bin/ls на /bin/lsr и посмотрите, что произойдет
    if ((ret = execl("/bin/ls","ls", "-lh", NULL)) < 0)
    {
        printf("error occurred: %s [ret = %d]", strerror(errno), ret);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Если Вы хотите захватить output:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_PIPES ( 2 )

int pipes[NUM_PIPES];

#define PAREN_RD_FD ( pipes[0] )
#define CHILD_WR_FD ( pipes[1] )

int main()
{
    pipe(pipes);

    if(!fork())
    {
        dup2(CHILD_WR_FD, STDOUT_FILENO);

        close(CHILD_WR_FD);
        close(PAREN_RD_FD);

        execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-lh", NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        char buffer[1024];
        int count;

        close(CHILD_WR_FD);

        count = read(PAREN_RD_FD, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
        if (count >= 0)
        {
            buffer[count] = 0;
            printf("Result: \n%s", buffer);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("IO Error\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

С использованием функции [popen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_SIZE ( 1024 )

void exec(const char* cmd, char* buf)
{
    FILE* stream = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (stream)
    {
        fread(buf, 1, BUF_SIZE - 1, stream);
        pclose(stream);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char out[1024];
    exec("ls -la", out);
    printf("Result:\n%s", out);
    return 0;
}
```

[Пример 1 в wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/l8qalmY7oeER4k8B)
[Пример 2 в wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wCrdaCPgoTeBXVyX)
[Пример 3 в wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cK5gx55t8YMzaG3v)